# Any way to install Bitwig 1.3 as deb package on Ubuntu Touch / Ubuntu Phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch, deb, multi-touch

As some of you may heared Bitwig Studio has released the next generation of Bitwig which included touch support on linux.

[Bitwig 1.3 multi-touch](http://www.bitwig.com/en/bitwig_1_3/)

Having that in mind i was thinking of installing bitwig 1.3 on my ubuntu phone (i have an older Nexus4 where i would test this first and an official Meizu MX4 Ubuntu Edition)

- Bitwig comes as a native debian package
- deb packages are not installable from scratch on ubuntu touch, i would need to make it read/write access
- The list of dependencies might be the biggest issue, as i dont know if these package are available on ubuntu touch (especially libjack which might be essential for audio):

  1. libcairo2
  2. libxcb-icccm4
  3. libxcb1
  4. libxcb-randr0
  5. libx11-xcb1
  6. libxkbfile1
  7. libxcursor1
  8. libstdc++6
  9. libc6
  10. libgcc1
  11. libpixman-1-0
  12. libfontconfig1
  13. libfreetype6
  14. libpng12-0
  15. libxcb-shm0
  16. libxcb-render0
  17. libx11-6
  18. zlib1g
  19. libxau6
  20. libxdmcp6
  21. libxfixes3
  22. libexpat1
  23. libxrender1
  24. libx11-6
  25. zlib1g
  26. libjack-jackd2-0
  27. xdg-utils
  28. libav-tools
  29. zenity

Is there a way i could install and test it?

Comment: Firstly, they have to port it to the ARM processor. Then one of two things should happen: either a fully functional xMir from Ubuntu team or the replacement of cairo-xcb by cairo-gles from Bitwig team.